# How to render rander rmarkdown file to markdown file with backtick styled code block

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I have a `test.Rmd` file.

`````
```{r}
1 + 1
````
`````

I render it to a markdown file with command `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", rmarkdown::md_document())`. The resulting code block is four space style. I want the backstick style.

````
```r
1 + 1
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the YAML header block to turn on Pandoc's `backtick_code_blocks` extension:

```
---
title: "Markdown file"
output: 
    md_document:
        variant: markdown+backtick_code_blocks
---
```

Comment: Following your answer, I get what I want using the command `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", rmarkdown::md_document(variant = "markdown_strict+backtick_code_blocks"))`.